# Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 issues After February 2021 Windows Update

Tags: dual-boot

I had a nice working dual boot system, Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Then I did the February 2021 Windows update and BAM! my world of pain began. No GRUB boot loader. System just booted straight into Windows. Ran a live Ubuntu USB and repaired GRUB. Still boots straight into Windows, no GRUB. Ran this in Windows

```
bcdedit set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

and that broke Windows boot, BIOS said no operating system detected, no GRUB either. I couldn't get anything to boot. At this point I thought, I'll just start again. Format drive, install Windows 10, then install Ubuntu. BIOS wouldn't detect or boot USB drive with Windows on it. So, I reset BIOS to defaults and away I went. Got Windows 10 on, did all the updates, then tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot. Now the Ubuntu installer is not detecting that I have Windows 10 installed.

I'm thinking that the Windows update has done something unusual, locked somethings that it doesn't normally do.

Anyone else having this issue? Any ideas what to do? (I was thinking maybe I'll just forget Windows and just use Ubuntu, but I like Photoshop and I'm not so good with GIMP)

Comment: I had a similar issue a few months back - not due to the feb update.. The following link helped https://www.techsupportpk.com/2020/04/how-to-fix-ubuntu-not-detecting-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Turns out that my system (Lenovo M92P) was booting in BIOS not UEFI.

Just for kicks I updated the BIOS to the newest (not sure this had anything to do with it).

Made a new bootable Windows USB with Rufus but this time GPT (for UEFI).

I set the BIOS to UEFI only but had to disable "secure boot" as Rufus doesn't make bootable USB drives that work without disabling it.

Installed Windows again. Updated Windows. Then I made another bootable Ubuntu USB with Rufus, again with GPT for UEFI. Installed alongside Windows boot manager (Ubuntu saw Windows this time).

When I first installed Ubuntu the computer missed GRUB and booted straight into Windows. I thought I was back to square one, but them I ran this command

```
bcdedit set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

in Windows (same as the above, but last time it broke Windows, probably because everything was running as BIOS not UEFI) and all has returned to normal. I get the familiar Grub bootloader and can choose which OS I want upon start up.